# Continuity of f

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Is the statement below true.If it is could someone provide a proof of this.If its not provide a counter example

$ f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$

$\implies  \exists \delta>0:$

(if   $|x-x_0|<\delta \implies  f(x) $  is continuous).

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You just wrote $f$ is continuous implies $f$ is continuous when $|x-x_0|<\delta$. Also, since $(P\implies Q)\implies R$ is not equivalent to $P\implies(Q\implies R)$ you need parentheses either way.

Comment: The correct statement is that : for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$. And this is the definition of continuity of $f$ at $x_0$. Do you want to prove this from the topological definition that the inverse image of an open set has to be open?

Comment: @AbishankaSaha I think he wants to prove (or actually disprove) that *if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then it's continuous in a neighborhood of $x_0$*. Wrong of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Outline:** This is not true. Let $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is irrational, and let $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is rational. Show that the only point of continuity of $f$ is at $x=0$.

Comment: Same answer, I was too slow :-)

Comment: Occasionally a Normand can be quick.